# Error "You must 'source' the script:" while trying to ativate python virtualenv on Windows10

Tags: powershell, python, virtualenv

python 3.7.1
Windows 10
Powershell

Steps taken:
create folder for envs
change to folder
`pip install virtualenv`
`virtualenv "abc"`
`abc\Scripts\activate`

This throws the error stated in the title. I have tried `activate` and `activate.ps1`. They both result in the error. `activate.bat` doesn't get the error but it doesn't work either.

I have tried running PS as administrator and searched google and stackoverflow. Myself and one other user on stackoverflow seem to be the only two people with this problem.

Details:

Output from activate.ps1:

```
PS D:\GoogDrive\flask> noc\Scripts\activate.ps1  
You must 'source' this script: PS> . noc\Scripts\activate.ps1  
PS D:\GoogDrive\flask>
```

Output from activate.bat:

```
PS D:\GoogDrive\flask> noc\Scripts\activate.bat  
PS D:\GoogDrive\flask>
```

Also, when I do `pip list`, it always shows me all the modules in my base install.

Comment: `activate` is a shell script for Unix. The correct command for Powershell is `abc/Scripts/activate.ps1`. You seem to have misspelled `Scripts` but then the error message would be different. Can you please [edit] your question to show *exactly* what output you get from `abc/Scripts/activate.ps1`?

Comment: Running as administrator is entirely the wrong thing to do here. The whole point of `virtualenv` is to separate your environment from system-wide settings and defaults which require privileged access to manipulate.

Comment: tripleee, re: admin rights, yes, that is a good point. I only tried it that way to eliminate rights as being the culprit. Thanks for your feed back! Also, "GoogDrive" is correct, its not misspelled on this PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error message specifically says, the correct way to run the script is to `source` it:

```
. noc\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

The single dot is an alias for the `source` command. This causes the script to be run in the current session, rather for the shell to start a new subshell, run the script, and exit (thus losing any environment changes that the script attempted to make).

Comment: I'm not a PowerShell person but in this case the error message is basically identical to a common error I see with Bash users.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks so much. This is my first question, I checked the green check mark, anything else I need to do?

Comment: That's all good, thank you very much. Clicking the up arrow is strictly optional, though of course I'd appreciate it. See also [help.](/help/someone-answers)